# Python: split single column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-cleaning

I am having a csv that should have been a json and I am trying to sort it in multiple columns

It could have been a json like this (if that helps):

```
{"username":"jane.doe@gmail.com"
   "app": [
        {"appid":"123456"
        "appname:"apppname"
        "scopes":["scope1","scope2"]}
        {"appid":"23456
        "appname:"apppname"2
        "scopes":["scope1","scope2"]}
{"username":john.doe@gmail.com"
   ...}
```

here is the data

| Value |
| --- |
| User: jane.doe@gmail.com |
| Client ID: CI1 |
| anonymous: False |
| displayText: app1 |
| nativeApp: False |
| userKey: uk1 |
| scopes: |
| http://scope1.com |
| http://scope2.com |
| Client ID: CI2 |
| anonymous: False |
| displayText: app2 |
| nativeApp: False |
| userKey: uk2 |
| scopes: |
| http://scopeapp2-1.com |
| http://scopeapp2-1.com |

It goes on and a user can have any number of apps and the apps can has many scopes.
Expected output

| User | anonymous | displayText | nativeApp | scopes | Client_id | userKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| jane.doe@gmail.com | false | app1 | false | http://scope1.com http://scope2.com | CI1 | UK1 |
| jane.doe@gmail.com | false | app2 | false | https://scopeapp2-1.com http://scopeapp2-2.com | CI2 | UK2 |

So i did it but I think my code is a bit ugly and was wondering if you had better ideas

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'User' in df.at[index,'value']:
        x=index
        df.at[x,'User']=df.at[index,'value']
    elif 'Client ID' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'Client_ID']=df.at[index,'value']
        x=x+1
    elif 'anonymous' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'anonymous']=df.at[index,'value']       
    elif 'displayText' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'displayText']=df.at[index,'value']   
    elif 'nativeApp' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'nativeApp']=df.at[index,'value']   
    elif 'userKey' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'userKey']=df.at[index,'value']
    elif 'http' in df.at[index,'value']:
        df.at[x,'scopes']=df.at[x,'scopes'] + ' ' +df.at[index,'value']
```

then I'll just drop the empty rows.
I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, all this elif is not very clean...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "csv that should have been a json"? The data you've shown isn't CSV nor JSON. You should provide a sample of the data in the exact format you have it. And an example of the data frame you need in the end.

Comment: Why does it have two UserKeys and two ClientIDs?

Comment: are you sure it's not YaML?  this looks simplest way to sort it out...

Comment: thank you for having a look, 
@YevhenKuzmovych I think it is more readable that way basically i just read_csv the file If that helps let's assume it's a dataframe already.

Comment: @LukasKaspras my bad sorry I have edited it

Comment: @RobRaymond wouldn't the file needs to be indented? Maybe it was at some point. I'll have a look, I don't know how a yaml can be converted to CSV with python, I'll check that out thank you :) . Even if that's the case, I am more interested in the way this problem can be solv

Comment: throw it into a dict as you parse?  split strings on ':'
if you have a user record -> dict[user]
if there's something in split[1] ':' then it's dict[user][this]
if there's nothing after  ':' then dict[user][this] = [] append the next values which have no ':'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is so close to being **YaML** it's simple to insert missing indentation and list separators to then load using `json_normalize()`

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from pathlib import Path
import yaml

raw = """User: jane.doe@gmail.com
Client ID: CI1
anonymous: False
displayText: app1
nativeApp: False
userKey: uk1
scopes:
http://scope1.com
http://scope2.com
Client ID: CI2
anonymous: False
displayText: app2
nativeApp: False
userKey: uk2
scopes:
http://scopeapp2-1.com
http://scopeapp2-1.com"""

fn = Path.cwd().joinpath("so.yaml")
with io.StringIO(raw) as f, open(fn, "w") as fw:
    while True:
        suffix = ""
        l = f.readline()
        if not l: break
        elif l.startswith("User:"): 
            prefix = ""
            suffix = "\napp:"
        elif l.startswith("Client ID:"): prefix = "  - "
        elif (" " in l) or l.startswith("scopes:"): prefix = "    "
        else: prefix = "    - "
        fw.write(f"{prefix}{l.strip()}{suffix}\n")

    
with open(fn) as f: myyaml = yaml.safe_load(f)
    
pd.json_normalize(myyaml, record_path="app", meta="User")
```

|  | Client ID | anonymous | displayText | nativeApp | userKey | scopes | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CI1 | False | app1 | False | uk1 | ['http://scope1.com', 'http://scope2.com'] | jane.doe@gmail.com |
| 1 | CI2 | False | app2 | False | uk2 | ['http://scopeapp2-1.com', 'http://scopeapp2-1.com'] | jane.doe@gmail.com |

Comment: This works very well and there is no cleaning afterward thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you have a csv file.

If you can count on the structure, ie, 1 User, 1 to N Client ID sections with a scopes section with 1 .. N urls you could do something like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from itertools import islice
    from pprint import pprint
    data = {}


    def fieldv(line):
        return line.rsplit(':', 1)[1].strip()


    users = []
    client_data = []
    user_record = None
    scopes = []
    with open(..., 'r') as infile:
        while line := infile.readline():
            if line.startswith('User'):
                user = fieldv(line)
                client_data = []
                user_record = {'User': user, 'client_data': client_data}
                users.append(user_record)
            elif line.startswith('http://'):
                scopes.append(line.strip())
            else:
                d = list(islice(infile, 5))
                scopes = []
                app = {'Client ID': fieldv(line),
                       'anonymous': fieldv(d[0]),
                       # other fields d[1], d[2]...,
                       'scopes': scopes}
                client_data.append(app)
```

Printing the users list with the data provided:

```
[{'User': 'jane.doe@gmail.com',
  'client_data': [{'Client ID': 'CI1',
                   'anonymous': 'False',
                   'scopes': ['http://scope1.com', 'http://scope2.com']},
                  {'Client ID': 'CI2',
                   'anonymous': 'False',
                   'scopes': ['http://scopeapp2-1.com',
                              'http://scopeapp2-1.com']}]}]
```

Comment: upvoted - very similar to approach I used, just I used YaML as way to build same structure as source file was almost YaML